# Why I can't use a block to add a leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

Here is the code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = kMenuIcon;
```

and here is my kMenuIcon:

```
#define kMenuIcon  ^{UIBarButtonItem *menuIcon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(revealLeftSidebar:)]; return menuIcon;};
```

But it return me the `unrecognized selector` error like this:

> -[**NSStackBlock** isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbfffd4b8 2013-09-09 11:30:57.788 Sircle[33182:c07] Uncaught
>   exception: -[**NSStackBlock** isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0xbfffd4b8

I tried that code, move away from the block, it works, but when I put it in the block, it doesn't. What's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Remove semicolon from the definition of `kMenuIcon`, and add `()` after the assignment: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = kMenuIcon();`

Comment: And (if you must do this at all) replace the reference to self in the block with a reference to self cast as __unsafe_unretained.

Answer (score 1):

The `leftBarButtonItem` is a `UIBarButtonItem *`, you are assigning a block.

Why don't you simply do this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *menuIcon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(revealLeftSidebar:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuIcon;
```

Comment: or even just assign it without the variable, on one line

Answer (score 1):

Youre assigning the block itself to leftBarButtonItem. You want to assign the *return* value of the block, so you must call it by appending the blocks #define name with ().

So:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = kMenuIcon();
```

Comment: But it is still strange that he would define a block and immediately invoke it, when all the block does is return a variable defined on the previous line. Basically, the whole thing is equivalent to just the expression initializing the variable.

Comment: Its not good design at all, but if they are putting it a header and using it in multiple view controllers i can see the line of reasoning. My point was to teach the distiction between block variables and block invocations. It takes practice a reading books to learn good design :)